# Carry the luggage for me, _________? A. Will you B. Won't you

Tags: grammaticality, negation, tag-questions, imperative-sentences

According to the answer sheet, B is the answer. Does that make A incorrect?
What difference do these 2 make in the meaning? Plus, is B more polite?
It seems kind of frustrated to me.

Comment: A is a rather rude and abrupt way of asking someone to carry your luggage. I don't find B particularly natural, but it _could_ be a rather indirect way of asking for help from someone you think might be willing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, either is grammatically correct, but they have different meanings.

So, "Carry the luggage for me, **won't** you?" implies the opposite: you **should** carry the luggage. It is therefore a polite offer. "Carry the luggage for me, **will you**?" implies the opposite: you **shouldn't** carry the luggage.

"will you" could be used when the speaker is frustrated that somebody hasn't done something already. It would usually have the word "just" at the beginning:

> Just carry the luggage for me, will you?

I guess the answer sheet said B was correct, as "will you" is a bit "aggressive" and may not be the best answer for practice.

More information on will you vs won't you [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397406/will-you-wont-you)